# insert images dynamically to horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am working on an android application that will get data from an xml file and insert it in a listview

but I want to change the UI and instead of displaying the data in a listview vertically, I want to display them horizontally in a scrollview

My question is if I have the following code

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="2dp">

            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:src="@drawable/i1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextOnImage11"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fantasia Reviews"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
                android:paddingLeft="2dp" 
                android:background="@drawable/txt_bg" 
                android:textSize="10dp" 
                android:paddingTop="2dp" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:width="0dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

how can I add more images and text dynamically from the java code ??

Thank you

Comment: This is one items template, right?

Comment: yes one item template it was just put to show how i would like it to be but with more items

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your intent would be to add another RelativeLayout with it's own image/text pair straight after the RelativeLayout that you have shown in your code sample?

In that case as it is not simply adding one more view, I would take the time to create a class that represents your "structure" that you want to insert.

e.g. A class called "TextImagePair" that extends "RelativeLayout"

```
public class TextImagePair extends RelativeLayout {
    public ReportDetailRow(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public TextImagePair(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public TextImagePair(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet, int i){
        super(context, attributeSet,i);
    }

    public TextImagePair(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, String text, int drawableResource) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        // Inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflator.inflate(R.layout.lay_textimagepair, this);

        TextView tvText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.layTextImagePair_textview);
        tvText.setText(text);

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.layTextImagePair_imageview);
        imgView.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawableResource));
    }
}
```

You would then have a seperate xml layout file (named lay_textimagepair in my code) that just contains the text and image views.

You would then add this to your view at run time with:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layParentView_liniearlayout);
TextImagePair tip = new TextImagePair(null,null,"Blah Blah Blah",R.drawable.something);
parent.addView(tip);
```

Sorry if there are any bugs in the above code but I am writing it without access to Eclipse!

Comment: it is very true what you said, I will try your code and let you know the results, Thanks!

Comment: Hope it works for you. Noticing the other questions you have asked recently, make sure you accept answers on questions. It's helps to build your reputation on stack overflow.